# Issue using multiple ISNULL entry conditions for a record-triggered flow

Tags: visual-workflow, asynchronous, recordtriggeredflow, isnull

I am running into issues when setting up an asynchronous flow to trigger based on multiple ISNULL conditions.

For context, there are two separate account look up fields. When one of these fields is updated from null to an account, this flow should fire.

**Current entry criteria:**

---

Any condition is met (OR)

Account 1 IS NULL equals FALSE

Account 2 IS NULL equals FALSE

Only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements

Include a Run Asynchronously path to access an external system after the original transaction for the triggering record is successfully committed

---

This works when both fields are null prior and one or both are populated. It does not work when one of the fields is already populated and the other is populated after.

Based on the debug logs it looks like it should be firing as you can see the coborrower account field updating from null to populated.
[image]

Does anyone know what is causing this or a work around?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the issue stems from this part:

```
Only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements
```

Have you tried changing that to Every time a record is updated and do this criteria:

(1 AND 2) OR (3 AND 4)

```
Account 1 Is Changed = True
Account 1 Is Null = False
Account 2 Is Changed = True
Account 2 Is Null = False
```

Comment: Unfortunately this flow has to run asynchronously so I have to use "Only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements" which prevents me from using the Is Changed criteria. Otherwise, this feels like it would be the best route!

Comment: Ahh yup I skipped over that part. So the use case is accounts are populated and then you're sending over to another system? Is this only a one time thing?